# Use Taylor Series to arrive at the expression for the forward approximation for a derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Use Taylor Series to arrive at the expression for the forward approximation for a derivative.
$$f'(x)\approx \frac1h\left(-\frac32f(x)+2f(x+h)-\frac12f(x+2h)\right)$$

I'm not sure how to even go about this so any help is sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$ (1): f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x) + O(h^3) $

$(2): f(x+2h) = f(x) + 2h f'(x) + \frac{(2h)^2}{2} f''(x) + O(h^3)$

Now,

$2 \times (1) - \frac{1}{2} \times (2) :$

$2f(x+h) - \frac{1}{2} f(x+2h) = \frac{3}{2} f(x) + hf'(x) +  (2\frac{h^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} 2h^2 ) f''(x) + O(h^3)$

$\Rightarrow -\frac32f(x)+2f(x+h)-\frac12f(x+2h) + O(h^3) = hf'(x) $

is the required result.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to get one error order better than the simple difference quotient. Please add the second derivatives in the computation.

Comment: @LutzL Fair 'nuff. Edited.